# Send response when window is closed

Tags: javascript, html

### The goal

Send `true` or `false` when window is closed.

### The problem

When I click on a button, a window is opened with `window.open();` syntax. What I  need seems to be simple: when the window is closed, return to the window that opened the popup a response from the server, that can be `true` or `false` — like the Facebook's API does.

**Someone knows how can I do this in a simple way?**

### Spotlight

I don't want to use jQuery because the page's CSS is overwriting the popup's CSS.

### Current syntax

**HTML:**

```
[...]
<a href="#" class="share" data-networkName="<?php echo $network->name; ?>">
    Share</a>
[...]
```

**JS:**

```
$(".share").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var networkName = $(this).data("networkName");

    window.open("share.php?network=" + networkName");
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

#### UPDATE

**receive.html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="openWindow()">Share</a>

<script>
  var new_window = null;

  function openWindow() {
    new_window = window.open('return.html');
  }

  // Callback Function that we will call in child window
  function sendMessage(message) {
    alert(message);
    new_window.close();
  }
</script>
```

**return.html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.messageParent();">Mark As Shared</a>

<script>
  function messageParent() {
    // Calls sendMessage function on the parent window.
    window.opener.sendMessage("Hello World!"); 
  }
</script>
```

You could then handle the return value that you would like to in the sendMessage function in the parent window.

This is the simplest method I could come up with. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Almost there, Brandon. How can I send, for example, a "Hello world!" message from that popup?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge - I have updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge - Did this help you? If it did please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".share").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var networkName = $(this).data("networkName");
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        window.open("share.php?network=" + networkName");
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

main.php's script:

```
$(".share").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var networkName = $(this).data("networkName");
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            window.open("share.php?network=" + networkName");
        }
    function send(msg) {
        //send msg to db or store as cookies
    }
    });
```

popup.html's script: [Let's say you have a share button called '#popup-btn']

```
$('#popup-btn').click(function() {
    window.opener.send('MSG SENT FROM POPUP {THEY SHARED SOMETHING}');
});
```

Comment: Almost there, Pixeladed. How can I send, for example, a "Hello world!" message from that popup?

Comment: what do you mean send? to the server perhaps?

Comment: When the popup opens, there is a "share" button and I need to know if the user shared something or not. In other words, I need to know if the user clicked on "share" button.

Comment: I think you already know because you trigger all the function within the `$(".share").on("click", function(event) {//function}`

Comment: The "share" button that I was referring is inside of the popup. In other words, I need to send a message from popup to main window asynchronously.